# Oracle.ORDS: How to return column as a JSON array?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I have a master table and a detail table.
I want to make a "GET" request to get something like this

```
select "id","name","color","etc",
(select json_arrayagg(regions returning clob) from tbl_regions r where r.id = t.id) regions from clients t;
```

and i want to have a json array in the result JSON.
BUT I have a string attribute in a reponse from ORDS service.
How to convert or to set type to a json array to a column

now i have a relust like this

```
{
..
..
..
"regions":"["1","2"]"
}
```

but i want a natural array without '"'

```
"regions":["1","2"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON results from ORDS should be aliased "{}some_name".
Without the braces the engine converts the result into an escaped string.
And I would return json_object per row, it could be easier for the client instead of the mix you are trying to do.

Comment: How to return an ampty array when my detail table have no dependent reccords?

Comment: @AndrewKondrashov please ask this as a new question

Comment: just warp the subselect into a NVL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!!!
It works!

I have to add a special alias with {}

```
select "id","name","color","etc",
(select json_arrayagg(regions returning clob) from tbl_regions r where r.id = t.id) "{}regions" from clients t;
```